# AngularJS $http.put not working in Firefox or Chrome. Works ok in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an AngularJS call for $http.get(). Works fine over CORS in browsers.
I have an AngularJS call for $http.post(). Only works if I set the Content-Type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Works fine over CORS in browsers.

I have an AngularJS call for $http.put(). I tried to set Content-Type headers to "**/**" wild card, it does not work for Firefox 36+ and Chrome 36+.  It gives me a CORS Blocked.  It works fine in IEx11

Is there a specific header for $http.put() or is this an issue with FF/Chrome?

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: remoteURL,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                processData: false,
                data: json,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });

Comment: Works in IE, but not in FF/Chrome

Comment: $http.put(
                remoteURL,
                data
                )
                .success(function (data, status, response) {
                    alert('OK');
                })
                .error(function (data, status, config) {
                    alert('Error');
                });

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding to REST controller method:

[HttpOptions]

[HttpPut]

web.config:

name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"

name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"

name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"

Comment: I'm having same problem can you provide code snippet which you solved